# Failed to deserialize sealed objects from Cipher input stream

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream, corrupt, javax.crypto

Why do I get an invalid stream header error when I read an object from a CipherInputStream ?
(edit: possibly due to re-use of Cipher object?, new version of sample code included below has resolved the issue.)

My program is trying to read from an ObjectInputStream which is using a CipherInputStream as a source (which is sourced from a file), ie:

File -> DeCipher Stream -> DeSerialize -> Object

The runtime error is:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720019
```

The write method in the example program listed below writes the file using a plain FileOutputStream **and** as a CipherOutputStream, so we have 2 files to examine.
The read method similarly attempts to read both files. The plain file is written and read without issues, however the encrypted file throws the exception.
If you look at the first 8 bytes of the plain file, you can see they are:

```
 0000000 254 355  \0 005   s   r  \0 031   j   a   v   a   x   .   c   r

          ac  ed  00  05  73  72  00  19  6a  61  76  61  78  2e  63  72
```

Where "ac ed 00 05" corresponds to the ObjectStream Magic and Version (ie the header): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html

BUT the 'corrupt' header reported by the Exception corresponds to the four bytes *after* the header: 73 72 00 19 !

It looks to me like the CipherInputStream is decrypting the stream correctly  but consuming or skipping the header itself and delivering the data starting at byte 5.

This is the bad output:

```
    run:
    Read Object (plain): Test
    Exception in readTest: 
    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720019
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is the code:

```
    package encryptedobjectstreamexample;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.security.*;
    import javax.crypto.*;
    import static javax.crypto.Cipher.*;
    import javax.crypto.spec.*;

    public class EncryptedObjectStreamExample {
        static boolean cipherOn = true;
        static final String fn = "C:/Temp/object.";
        static final byte[] keyBytes = "MySecretPass1234".getBytes();
        static final byte[] iv = "initialialvector".getBytes();
        static String testObject = "Test";
        Cipher c;
        AlgorithmParameters ap;
        IvParameterSpec ivp;
        Key k;

        public EncryptedObjectStreamExample() {
            try {
                c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                ap = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("AES");
                ivp = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
                ap.init(ivp);
                k = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.println("Failed Constructor:\n" + ex);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        public void writeTest() {
            // Object -> Serialize -> Cipher Stream -> File
            try {
                c.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, k, ap);
                OutputStream ostrp = new FileOutputStream(fn+"p");
                OutputStream ostrx = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fn+"x"),c);
                try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(ostrp)) {
                    oos.writeObject(new SealedObject(testObject, c));
                }
                try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(ostrx)) {
                    oos.writeObject(new SealedObject(testObject, c));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception in writeTest: \n" + e);
            }
        }

        private void readTest() {
            // File -> DeCipher Stream -> DeSerialize -> Object
            try {
                c.init(DECRYPT_MODE, k, ap);
                InputStream istrp = new FileInputStream("C:/Temp/object.p");
                InputStream istrx = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Temp/object.x"),c);
                try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(istrp)) {
                    String result = (String) (((SealedObject) ois.readObject()).getObject(c));
                    System.out.println("Read Object (plain): " + result);
                }
                try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(istrx)) {
                    String result = (String) (((SealedObject) ois.readObject()).getObject(c));
                    System.out.println("Read Object (encrypt): " + result);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception in readTest: \n" + e);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EncryptedObjectStreamExample eos = new EncryptedObjectStreamExample();
            eos.writeTest();
            eos.readTest();
        }
    }
```

Edit:
I've re-jigged the code somewhat so that I use different Cipher objects for the stream and the Seal operations: x.sealdob and x.iostream

This modified code now runs correctly, both files are written and read back without error:

This is the new (good) output:

```
    run:
    Read Object (plain): Test
    Read Object (encrypt): Test
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is the updated code (that works):

```
    package encryptedobjectstreamexample;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.security.*;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.crypto.*;
    import static javax.crypto.Cipher.*;
    import javax.crypto.spec.*;

    public class EncryptedObjectStreamCipherX {

    static boolean cipherOn = true;
    static final String FN = "C:/Temp/object.";
    static final byte[] keyBytes = "MySecretPass1234".getBytes();
    static final byte[] IV = "initialialvector".getBytes();
    static String testObject = "Test";
    Xipher x;
    Key k;

    private class Xipher {

        AlgorithmParameters ap;
        Cipher iostream, sealedob;
        static final String ALG = "AES";

        Xipher() {
            try {
                iostream = Cipher.getInstance(ALG + "/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                sealedob = Cipher.getInstance(ALG + "/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                ap = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(ALG);
                ap.init(new IvParameterSpec(IV));
                k = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidParameterSpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EncryptedObjectStreamCipherX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        void encryptMode() {
            try {
                iostream.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, ALG), ap);
                sealedob.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, ALG), ap);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EncryptedObjectStreamCipherX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        void decryptMode() {
            try {
                iostream.init(DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, ALG), ap);
                sealedob.init(DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, ALG), ap);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EncryptedObjectStreamCipherX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public EncryptedObjectStreamCipherX() {
        try {
            x = new Xipher();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed Constructor:\n" + ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void writeTest() {
        // Object -> Serialize -> Cipher Stream -> File
        try {
            x.encryptMode();
            OutputStream ostrp = new FileOutputStream(FN + "p");
            OutputStream ostrx = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FN + "x"), x.iostream);
            try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(ostrp)) {
                oos.writeObject(new SealedObject(testObject, x.sealedob));
            }
            try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(ostrx)) {
                oos.writeObject(new SealedObject(testObject, x.sealedob));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception in writeTest: \n" + e);
        }
    }

    private void readTest() {
        // File -> DeCipher Stream -> DeSerialize -> Object
        try {
            x.decryptMode();
            InputStream istrp = new FileInputStream("C:/Temp/object.p");
            InputStream istrx = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Temp/object.x"), x.iostream);
            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(istrp)) {
                String result = (String) (((SealedObject) ois.readObject()).getObject(x.sealedob));
                System.out.println("Read Object (plain): " + result);
            }
            try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(istrx)) {
                String result = (String) (((SealedObject) ois.readObject()).getObject(x.sealedob));
                System.out.println("Read Object (encrypt): " + result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception in readTest: \n" + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EncryptedObjectStreamCipherX eos = new EncryptedObjectStreamCipherX();
        eos.writeTest();
        eos.readTest();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try just reading the decrypted bytes from the encrypted file and comparing them to the bytes you read from the un-encrypted file? Such as length? It seems like you are close to doing that, but you're just using the exception output.

Comment: The code above writes and then reads 2 files, one using the Cipher streams, one just plain File streams, this is precisely to illustrate the issue ,, that the CipherStream version fails on read. I think I am satisfied now that this is not an issue with wrapping streams in streams nor with sealed objects, rather it is because I used the same  Cipher object to initialize the Cipher Stream as I use to unseal the objects .. somehow it is consuming the header .. may be a peek-ahead of some sort going on?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense. You don't need both the `Cipher` streams *and* the `SealedObject`, and if you consider the actual order of execution of all of these with respect to the `Cipher` you will see that it isn't symmetrical as between writing and reading.

Lose the  `SealedObject`, or lose the `Cipher` streams.

Comment: Even if you remove the SealedObject. The way they read/write they're not properly encrypting/decrypting.

Comment: @Matt With `CipherInput/OutputStreams` in there? Why not?

Comment: I am not sure, when I tried their code it doesn't work, the decrypted bytes are different. I think it should work, but there is something wrong.

Comment: @matt Cannot reproduce. I got `"Test"` back.

Comment: You're right, I had made a silly mistake.

Comment: I've found the issue can be resolved by using **different Cipher objects** for the CipherInputStream and the Sealed operations (in the code above I reused the same object). Something else I noticed is that CipherInputStreams do not support mark/reset -- that might be relevant, though I would have hoped for a mark/reset not supported exception rather than it silently doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @Mel The issue is pointless. Encrypting twice is not twice as secure. `mark()/reset()` have exactly nothing to do with it, and your speculation that it is 'silently doing the wrong thing' is not only baseless but nonsensical. How can it do *anything* if it isn't even there?

Comment: @EJP Encrypting twice is as pointless as using a secure protocol over a secure wireless connection. But that wasn't the question I asked. Pointless or not, it didn't work, and I believed it should have. Turns out the bug was the fact I was using the Cipher object twice.